# Not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip

I have a wheel that I can install in my host computer, but can not be installed on a docker container. Some details:

- OS is the same in both (Ubuntu 20.04)
- Python is the same in both (3.6.15), but have been compiled at different moments (so maybe they have different flags, I can not say)
- `pip` is the same in both systems (`pip 21.3.1`)

I am running the install command with:

```
pip install ./coverage-5.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

My host system is happy, but the docker container fails with:

```
ERROR: coverage-5.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I would like to know exactly what criteria `pip install` is using to decide whether the package is installable or not:

- is it using details about the OS? Which ones? Where are those read from? If I know this, I can understand what is the difference between one system and the other. In my opinion they are identical, but maybe I am missing something
- is it using details about Python itself, apart from the version? The version is the same, but maybe enabled features are different. How can I check this?

### EDIT

After tampering with the `pip` sources, it seems my wheel is tagged `cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64` according to pip, but the docker system supports (amongst a gazillion more), `cp36-cp36dm-manylinux2010_x86_64`. That's the closest one, but there is a `d` which I do not know what it means.

So now I need to understand the difference between `cp36m` and `cp36dm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp36dm` is the ABI tag, and the `d` means a debug build. Your docker container seems to be using a debug build of Python 3.6, which is incompatible with C extension code compiled for non-debug builds. (Python 3.8 [removes](https://bugs.python.org/issue36465) this incompatibility, but you're on 3.6.)

Comment: Yepp, I just dicovered as much after recompiling my python without the `--with-pydebug` flag. Thanks, upvoted and accepted.